# Xcode12: Colours defined in a xcassets file in a Swift Local Package does not show Dark Appearance when applying them via IB Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, xcasset

From the Swift tools version of 5.3 on and, we can bundle our resources within the Swift package. Following that, I included an `xcassets` catalog with my colors in a helper UI Local Package. When accessing them programmatically from my main target with

```
init?(named name: String, 
   in bundle: Bundle?, 
compatibleWith traitCollection: UITraitCollection?)
```

it works fine. However, when running in Dark Mode and applying the colors via `IB Storyboard`, it always shows the one for **Any Appearance** instead of the one set for **Dark Appearance**, even if both are discoverable and visible from IB.
I am using `// swift-tools-version:5.3` and Xcode Version 12.1 (12A7403)

Comment: Did you find any kind of solution or still nothing? I found a thread here about this topic without any responses yet: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/673341

Comment: @AlexandreNussbaumer not yet, hopefully it will be fixed in future Xcode releases